# Difference between autoscaling vs application-autoscaling IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

would like to know whats difference between below to in terms of IAM policy

```
application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy

autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy
```

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is that [`application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/put-scaling-policy.html) provides permissions to create and update [Application Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html) scalable targets - which supports scaling a range of services such as DynamoDB and SageMaker.

[`autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/put-scaling-policy.html) is for creating and updating traditional [EC2 auto scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html) groups.